# Can't get specific data from MySql

Tags: java, mysql, clause

I want to populate a TableView with players from MySQL database. To load all players I am using

```
public void loadPlayerData() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Connection conn = ConnectionDB.connector();

    ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM player") ;

    while (rs.next()) { playersList.add(new Players
            (rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("familyName"),
                    rs.getString("email"), rs.getString("activeTeam")));

    }
    rs.close();
```

and it works fine..
but I need to load only specific players that belong to a team (the name of the team is displayed in a TextField) and I did the following :

```
    public void loadPlayerData() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Connection conn = ConnectionDB.connector();
        String s = teamName.getText();
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM player WHERE activeTeam='" + s + "'") ;
        while (rs.next()) { playersList.add(new Players
                (rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("familyName"),
                        rs.getString("email"), rs.getString("activeTeam")));
        }
        rs.close();
```

but it doesn't load anything... I guess I am doing wrong in the syntax,writing wrong the WHERE clause, but all I researched pointed me to the same thing so I guess I have to ask here

Comment: Print your exceptions instead of throwing them.

Comment: You are exposed to being attacked by SQL INJECTIONS.

Comment: In production code use prepared-sql-statements and NOT the sql string + variable as a string. If the string is static that is okayish, but if anything from user input is read and placed into your statement always go with prepared statements.

Comment: The sql statement itself looks good. Check your database for typos, whitespace, upper/lowercase e.t.c. your row might be "activeTeam " with a whitespace or whatnot to crash it.

Comment: @Sedrick _Print your exceptions instead of throwing them._ - this is __horrible__ advice. exceptions should be thrown. Hence the name. "Print them and move on" is a fine way to have one error explode into 85 stack traces, with all but the first completely irrelevant, because your code is continuing on in states that it wasn't designed to operate in.

Comment: I did not say print and move on. I said print them. How else is the OP going to know what exception errors are happening? Maybe I should have said catch and print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Rzwitserloot gave an excellent explanation, I suggest the following approach

**Edit**

Added **try with resources construct** so it can prevent leaks.

```
 public void loadPlayerData() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        try (Connection connection = ConnectionDb.connector) {
            String s = teamName.getText();
            PreparedStatement myStmt;
            myStmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from player where activeTeam = ?");
            myStmt.setString(1, s);
            try (ResultSet rs = myStmt.executeQuery()) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    playersList.add(new Players
                            (rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("familyName"),
                                    rs.getString("email"), rs.getString("activeTeam")));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: just did it and it worked! :) thanks a lot!

Comment: @noxus010 please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @rzwitserloot thanks for the correction, I focused on the prepared-statement part so I forgot about the leaking part my apologies.

Comment: @Dren nice job :) I retracted my comment and flipped the vote.

Answer (score 2):

This is very much not how to do DBs in java.

1. **This is a security leak**.

Imagine `s` is: `"whatever' OR true; DROP TABLE player CASCADE; EXEC 'format c: /y'; --"

The right way is to use `PreparedStatement`.

2. It leaks like a sieve.

Connections, statements, *and* ResultSets **all** need to be closed after use. Even if exceptions are thrown. Use try-with-resources to get this right.

It probably 'doesnt work' because there's an additional space in the teamName field or whatnot.

Comment: @zeg using a static string and a Prepared Statement solved it... apparently the TextField was giving a string with a blank space which I had to remove.,.. thanks a lot!